# php mail(), как сделать ссылку в письме текстом

Tags: php, email

Отправляю код для вставки на сайт через email при помощи `mail()`. 
В письме скрипт вида:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bla_bla.ru/file.js?[uid]"></script>`.
При открытии письма ссылка `src` становится кликабельной ссылкой, а требуется, чтоб как и все остальное была просто текстом.
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.
Content-type: text/html;
С `Content-type: text/plain;` все так же ссылка.

Comment: Радуйтесь что ещё код показывается в письме.. )) многие системы могут просто удалить любой код в тексте письма, а зачем мучаетесь ? вставьте ваш код, например, в .txt файл и отправляйте attach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку у вас тип контента HTML, я бы посоветовал использовать средства HTML, то есть заключить опасный контент, который должно быть передан как есть, в тег `pre` или `code`

То есть что-то вроде

```
<code><script type="text/javascript" src="http://bla_bla.ru/file.js?[uid]"></script></code>
```

или

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bla_bla.ru/file.js?[uid]"></script>
</pre>
```

Смотрите что больше по смыслу подойдет

Материалы:

- http://htmlbook.ru/html/code
- http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre

Также посмотрите:

- http://htmlbook.ru/html/plaintext

Comment: Спасибо, до вашего ответа именно так и сделал! Но благодарю за ответ!!!